# How is this happening with DA and PA?

Tags: seo, moz

I have had this website online for over a year now and the DA is 1 and the PA is 1

https://fantasiarestaurant.pt/ (link for reference)

The one below has a DA of 3 and PA of 5 and has only been online a month... (and that's just from a backlink from my main website)

http://total-refurb.pt/

How is this possible? Both websites have a backlink from my website.

Is this something to worry about?

I've checked both sites, both are using SEO Yoast plugin, both have their website XML file submitted to Google Search Console, and I can confirm both sites are set to be crawled by search engines.

Any ideas?